# How to download xml file from server in IE using Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have to download a xml file from server using IE browser.

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
       response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachement; filename=xyz.xml");
```

Its working fine for other browsers, but in IE it shows xml output on browser.

How can I fix it? Please, help  :) thanks

Comment: It seems like IE (again) doesn't follow the standards then..

Comment: did u add : 'response.buffer=true' ?

Comment: you can try with changing MIME type handling of IE

Comment: I am tried content-type xml,x-download but its not fix. Can u pls suggest which content-type should I use?

Comment: I don't think it's mandatory for browsers to support the Content-Disposition header field so it's possible that some browsers don't. Saying that, I thought IE did support it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `Content-type` is wrong. You need to set all these headers. It works for me in all browsers.

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Content-type", "application-download");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```